# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

Im trying to get the title `content("GIGABYTE")` using python in the picture below.

I used:

```
containers= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})
brand = containers[0].div.div.a.img["title"]
```

but I get this error according to this line:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'
```

[image: this picture is an html content of a site i try to use web scraping method]

Comment: it'll really be better if you provided the code to obtain that html content

Comment: Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html that we can test with, not as an image. Include the URL if possible.

Comment: each item in `containers` should contain a `<img alt="GIGABYTE ..." title="GIGABYTE ..."/>` tag, which you can extract the `'title'` text via: `[c.find('img')['title'] for c in containers]`

Comment: https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=graphics+card&N=-1&isNodeId=1

thats the link
I clicked inspect on the brand "GIGABYTE" near the eggs

Answer (score 0):

You can use css [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) in [descendant combination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) with [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). `.item-brand img[title]`  means `img` elements with attribute `title` having parent with class `.item-brand`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=graphics+card&N=-1&isNodeId=1'
res  = requests.get(url, headers  = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')

items = [item['title'] for item in soup.select('.item-brand img[title]')]
print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each item in the `item-containers` has an associated `<img>` tag from which you can extract its `title=` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=graphics+card&N=-1&isNodeId=1'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
containers = page_soup.find_all("div",{"class":"item-container"})
titles = [str(c.img['title']) for c in containers]
```

should create a list of titles:

```
>>> print(titles)
['LITE-ON DVD Burner Black SATA Model iHAS124-14', 'ASUS DRW-24B1ST/BLK/B/AS Black SATA 24X DVD Burner - Bulk - OEM', ... 'GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 2070 GAMING OC WHITE 8G Video Card, GV-N2070GAMINGOC WHITE-8GC']
```